# moment.diff function does not work properly with dates passed as strings

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment.diff function to calculate time duration between 2 dates.

My code is like this:

```
function calculateDurationBetweenDates(now, then){    
    if(!now || !then){        
        return;        
    }

    var ms = moment(then, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(now, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"));        
    var d = moment.duration(ms);        
    var s = Math.floor(d.asHours()) + moment.utc(ms).format(":mm:ss");

    return s;
}

calculateDurationBetweenDates ("2016-10-08 11:29:23","2016-10-08 10:29:23");
```

this gives me result in negative as `-1:00:00`.

I dont understand why .

Comment: Maybe it's a timezone problem ?

Comment: I don't see the problem... There is exactly 1 hour difference between those dates... Are you bothered by the fact the number is negative? If so, just reverse the dates or use `Math.abs()`. Also your format is incorrect, it should be `YYYY-MM-DD` and *NOT* `DD-MM-YYYY`.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the dates around:

`var ms = moment(now, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(then, "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss"));`

A negative is the expected response if you're asking for the diff between a *later date* and an *earlier date*. If you want a non-negative just switch them round.